# What are basic checks to be done yearly

Tags: blood-tests, test, urine-test

I am a reasonably healthy 47 yo male. Not hypochondriac.

I am wondering which basic medical tests should be performed, and in which cycle.

I am thinking about tests per se (blood, urine,...), technology-based ones (chest x-ray if this is still a thing, for instance) and basic ones like blood pressure or heart rate.

Are there some which are recommended and make sense? I am particularly asking for those which are "wide spectrum" and which are likely to trigger attention when they are wrong (as opposed to some specialized markers for instance)